# Complex user relationships in Rails/Devise app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise

Rails app using Devise for user authentication. Started simple, now getting quite complex.

There are 3 kinds of user that will be logging in to the site: Admin, Teacher, Parent. I have a single Devise `User` model and `User.role` string for these. There is a `Student` model (which doesn't log in) and a `Lesson` model.

These are the relationships I need:

- Lesson belongs to one Student
- Student has many Lessons
- Student has many Teachers
- Student belongs to one Parent
- Parent has many Students
- Teacher has many Students

Basic functionality of the site: Teachers log in and make lessons for their students. Parents log in and see all lessons for their kids (students). Admins log in and can CRUD teachers, parents and students.

I have most of it working but got stumped when I tried to implement 'student has many teachers' and 'parent has many students'. My initial (incorrect) assumptions were that a student only has one teacher and that a parent just has one child at the school.

So it seems that using a `User.role` string won't suffice for these relationships.

Any advice or general concepts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a third model and using `has_many :through =>` to link everything together. I wanted to keep a single Devise user model and use a `.role` for authorization.

The third model I created was `Timeslot`, which is essentially where a teacher and student interact. Ideally I would have called it `class` or `session` but they're both reserved words.

```
# timeslot.rb
class Timeslot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :student
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLES = %w[admin teacher parent]
  has_many :timeslots
  has_many :students, through: :timeslots
end

# student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :timeslots
  has_many :users, through: :timeslots
end
```

This allows a user with a `teacher` role to have many `students` and vice-versa. The `Student` model has a `parent_id` column which stores the `id` of the user with role `parent`. That part is still a bit clunky but it works fine for now. I'm sure I'll have to refactor to something more elegant if the app has to scale.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a join table, ie a has_and_belongs_to_many relation?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

As I see it:

```
class Student
  belongs_to :parent
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
end

class Parent
  has_many :students
end

class Teacher
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end
```

Comment: Would that require separate Deivse user models? I'd like to keep a single log in process for all visitors. How could I keep one Devise `User` model and still use your suggestion above?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways of solving this, what i understand is that you have solved this much but you have made things bit complex.

you can simply have 1 model `User' and remaining things can be polymorphic.
You can move the common attributes in User and separate the remaining in their corresponding models.

It would be much better if had a look at code.

Thanks